# jQuery click event never triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(function (){
    $('a.folder').click(function() {
       // code goes here ...
    }
});
```

And the following html code:

```
<a class="folder" href="GetFilesAndFolders?rootFolder=Exigences">Etudes de cas</a>
```

Whenever I click on the link, the javascript code is never reached. I must say that this html code is generated dynamically after the page loaded. Is this the reason? Any workaround?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes That's not true. Maybe he wants the default behavior to happen, in addition to his js doing something

Comment: you have +3K rep, dont you think googling might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you attach the click handler it's possible that your anchor doesn't exist, try using this:

```
$(function (){
    $(document.body).on('click', 'a.folder', function() {
       // code goes here ...
    });
});
```

using this [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the click event will fire even if your anchor created dynamically after this code.

Comment: Please tell OP that you used Deligates !

Comment: Been having a ton of issues trying to get dynamically created anchors to work correctly, this worked the charm, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", "a.folder", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('a .folder was clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="folder" href="GetFilesAndFolders?rootFolder=Exigences">Etudes de cas</a>
```

Comment: dont answer on obvious dublicates

Comment: This is also wrong - the `a.folder` selector will not account for dynamically added elements. You'll need to bind to an element higher up in the hierarchy for that. Like so: `$("body").on("click, "a.folder", function() { });`